# What happens if I edit a folder while copying it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, file-transfer

Suppose I have a large folder and copy it. The copy takes a couple hours. While it's copying, I add some sub-folders and files to it. Does this pose any risk to confusing the OS and corrupting the metadata about the files during the copy? Am I guaranteed anything about whether any added files/subdirectories will/won't be included in the copy?

And out of curiosity, what happens if I actually edit a *file* while it's being transferred? Will that potentially corrupt the file at either the source or destination?

Similarly, what about file/folder deletions during copies (some light is shed on this for *nix OS's [here](https://superuser.com/questions/251129/moving-a-file-while-its-in-use-how-does-it-work))?

I'm curious about the answer for other OS's too, but this question is specifically about this situation on Windows 7.

Comment: You won't be able to edit a file while it is being transferred. Whatever program is transferring it will already have it open (and hopefully in exclusive mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can add files/folders to the directory that is being copied, however, I would imagine wherever the system is in terms of copying, it may or may not pick up the newly-added data.  Best rule of thumb, just don't. Wait until the data transfer is done.